# SQL- "Login failed for user" but that user cannot be found

Tags: sql-server

I have a situation: on a customer's server, there is installed both SQL Server 2017 and 2014 installed. On the one with 2014 I have developed some `stored procedures` that worked perfectly. After restoring the databases from 2014 to 2017, and running those procedures, I get the error:

> SQLState = 28000, NativeError = 18456 Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver
>   13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'ALL\ENTST15$'.

The idea is that when I'm trying to add a new login, the one SQL is looking for, I cannot find it in any directory. I'm a bit stuck.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

**EDIT**

[image]

Comment: Error 18456 has different [states](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_protocols/2006/02/21/understanding-login-failed-error-18456-error-messages-in-sql-server-2005/) that describe the exact problem, but you'll need to consult the error log for them. Most likely, your database is not contained and you didn't issue a `CREATE LOGIN` on the server to allow the user to log in in the first place, leaving the user account orphaned.

Comment: But what's the user in the first place? It's lie ALL\ENTST15$ where `ALL` stands for the domain and `ENTST15$` is the name of the instance.

Comment: `ENTST15$` is the computer account. As to why a login is happening with the computer account, I don't know, I'm not running your client. Is it a service running as a network service, by any chance? (To SQL Server, whether local or remote, this is an account like any other, and needs a login like any other.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert - I edited my post. The ones that handles `SQL` are not using a network service, only those showed in print screen.

Comment: Do any *other* queries work or is the stored procedure the only thing failing? Is it using any kind of linked server or ad-hoc connection to a remote server, which could mean the problem is that SQL Server itself cannot log in? And how are you running those stored procedures to begin with (i.e. what is the client)?

Comment: @JeroenMostert - what do you mean by "what is the client"?. These stored procedures are on a custom DB and I tried to run manually a stored procedure (right click -> execute) but they would be part of job. Also, the stored procedures is looking for the information on another database, on the same server, so my `FROM` clause is something like `FROM DatabaseName.Schema.Table`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176071/discussion-between-srkkk-and-jeroen-mostert).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after a few days after I have tried everything, literally everything, found on the internet, uninstalling the `SQL Server 2014` did the trick for me. Probably not the most recommended way, but it worked for me. Peace!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have orphaned users after the restore:
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1590/understanding-and-dealing-with-orphaned-users-in-a-sql-server-database/

Pretty much there are users in the 'database' but not in on the new SQL server you have restored to.  The article goes into more details but those users are orphaned and you can 'relink' them if you make new users on the server and run a built in stored procedure.

There is 'automated' code to fix this that people have written using this stored procedure:

`sp_change_users_login`

```
sp_change_users_login [ @Action = ] 'action'   
[ , [ @UserNamePattern = ] 'user' ]   
[ , [ @LoginName = ] 'login' ]   
[ , [ @Password = ] 'password' ]  
[;]
```

You can read the details about it here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-change-users-login-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

I think every MSSQL dba ends up in this spot at some time or another!

Comment: I ran the queries on both servers, but 0 rows as result.

Comment: But what's the user in the first place? It looks like `ALL\ENTST15$` where `ALL` stands for domain and `ENTST15$` is the name of the instance.

Comment: Ah, my answer might not be on the right track.  Orphaned users _usually_ refers to the mixed-mode SQL users, I'm not sure about it applies to domain users.